# git push of subtree-remote pushed the entire repo, how to undo?

Tags: git, github

I [Git merged](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-git-subtree-merges) my repo [feklee-node](https://github.com/feklee/feklee-node) into my repo [san](https://github.com/feklee/san). Commands

```
$ git remote add -f node git@github.com:feklee/feklee-node.git
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories feklee-node/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=node/ -u node/master
$ git commit # done from Emacs Magit IIRC
$ mv node/ nodes/pcb/
```

Then I did some changes in the repo *san*, and I wanted to get the changes in the subtree back into *feklee-node*. So I did (which obviously was a bad idea):

```
$ git push node master # node = git@github.com:feklee/feklee-node.git
```

This pushed the entire contents of *san* into *feklee-node*. Oh no!

*How do I undo this massive git push?*

And also I wonder how to push only the subtree.

## Update

I reverted back to an old commit, rewriting history:

```
$ git reset --hard 87b2d1aaea1c0a628c4725e2ea16682f344f102e
$ git push --force
```

Here I was lucky because I still had a browser tab open with the GitHub repo in the state before the massive push. It showed the above hash.

Answer (score 1):

In order to undo a commit use

```
git revert
```

Pushing only to a subtree should look something like this:

```
git subtree push --prefix=my/folder subtree_origin master
```

Comment: But I want to undo the massive multi-MB push, to get [feklee-node](https://github.com/feklee/feklee-node) to where it was before, a small light-weight repo that I kept in sync with another user's [repo](https://github.com/rampadc/feklee-node).